# How to prevent process from knowing Network is up?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, local-area-network

Fist let's block all Incoming, Outgoing signals 
via iptables.

> vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
```

start iptables:

```
 service iptables start
```

My Ethernet Cable is plugged in.
let's try something via terminal

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

that is all. just 1 line. after that it **stalls**.
clearly iptables is blocking it successfully

now I am going to disconnect my Ethernet cable.
my internet is disconnected.

let's try it again:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

this time .. instantly.. it returns that message.

Clearly, weather it is "ping" or any other program..
it is determining if a network interface is up or not
before it executes it's internet command.

of course soon as it executes.. it is not able to pass through
iptable rules. but what seems evident is.. it does not
first consult to the iptables..

it first checks to see if a network interface is connected
or not.

I would like to figure out how I can manually let it know
that network interface is connected.

in other words unless I tell it network interface is up..
it should simply behave the same way it behaves
when network interface is not connected
( when the ethernet cable is not plugged in)

how can this be done ?

Comment: *Clearly, weather it is "ping" or any other program..
it is determining if a network interface is up or not
before it executes it's internet command.* No, it's not clear at all.  Why can't whatever "internet command" get called act differently when you unplug the cable?  Just because it acts differently under different conditions doesn't mean it checks anything.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, so any internet command simply passes through a specific gate then before it hits the firewall ?

Comment: Whatever "internet command" is being run is more likely a system call such as [`sendto()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendto.html) and that system call is going to act differently under different conditions.  What's likely happening in your `ping` case is IPTABLES silently drops the outgoing packet - totally legal since UDP packets can be dropped for any reason - so the `ping` command never gets a return packet.  When you unplug the cable, `sendto()` (assuming that's what `ping` uses) fails instantly with an error since there is no network available.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by preventing an application from "knowing the network is up"?

Comment: You keep asking this question, under the guise of different users (see http://serverfault.com/questions/829131/deny-ping-network-access-w-o-iptables), although sadly the lengthy exchange you and I had in comments there has been deleted.  What is it going to take to convince you that you're asking a meaningless question?

Comment: @Andrew Henle, when ethernet cable is not connected.. how does the program get a return packet to know network is not connected ?

Comment: @NexttoZero Learn about setting SUID & iptables block by user already. It solves your question. Ping will display:
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
if blocked by this method

Comment: @Andrew Henle, when the ethernet cable is unplugged.. network is disconnected.. who sends a packet to the program telling it network is not connected ? obviously not firewall ( iptables ) clearly the system itself is doing it.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, I have tried the SUID & Iptables method. If the program is designed not to respect the return message.. it can choose to disregard it.

Comment: I do not belive "REJECT" or "DROP" can simulate the same thing the KERNEL is able to simulate to the program. I do not belive there is a way to make ping return the same error message ( **connect: Network is unreachable** ) based on a rule in the iptables.

Comment: @NexttoZero: Please don't continue this line of questioning, especially not while creating new accounts.  It doesn't lead anywhere. Also, you have been told numerous times now that what you want to do doesn't work and and doesn't make sense so maybe you should start considering that whatever you want do to might not be so good an idea after all.

Comment: It's a shame, because down in the middle here, under all the OP's misunderstandings about userspace, kernel space, and networking stacks, there is a single quite-good question: *how do you get `iptables` to reject locally-originating outbound traffic in a way that a normally-written userspace program will consider to be a fatal error*.  I have been genuinely surprised by how difficult it is to do that, so I guess *I* learned something!

Comment: @MadHatter, look at the world compared to 20 years ago.. linux distros used to be 80 mb.. now they are 800mb minimum.. and they climb to 2-3-4 gb.. they used to make fun of windows.. now they have become the new windows.. I will not feel safe using linux connected to internet until I solve this issue and disable internet access to all programs then selectively grant to the ones I trust.

Comment: Would you prefer to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52687/discussion-on-how-to-prevent-process-from-knowing-network-is-up)?

Comment: Discuss ? You said you could not go any further because you did not know if it could be done

Comment: Notice how a beautiful question gets -3 votes.. and then gets placed on hold with intent to be deleted ? this is the world we live in.

Comment: I do not think discussing it is the right way. I just have to re-post the question with the new data.. kernel is sending a response to programs.. programs are not checking to see if network is up then acting upon the info.

Comment: @NexttoZero this is not even *close* to a beautiful question.  I'm exhausted by the effort of trying to help it get this far, and all we get in return is abuse for a highly-respected moderator.  If you want people to help you, you have a funny way of going about it.

Comment: @NexttoZero: Before posting any other question on [SF], please consider that we are a site for professional system administrators and your personal desktop system is explicitly [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). This aspect got lost in all the back and forth you created.

Comment: @MadHatter, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341004/

Answer (score 4):

> Clearly, weather it is "ping" or any other program.. it is determining if a network interface is up or not before it executes it's internet command.

No, it isn't.  Here's (some of) the output from `strace ping 8.8.8.8` from a system *with no functional network interface*:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, 16) = -1 NETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

To answer your *specific* question, when a userspace process asks the kernel to send data to a remote system when there is no networking subsystem available, it gets back an error appropriate to the situation.  Note the absence of any *query* about whether the network is available; the userspace program goes right ahead and asks for connectivity, but gets an immediate error because the kernel knows it can't be satisfied.  It's no different from trying to write a file on a file system that is out of space (error 28, no space left on device) or when you've exceeded your disk quota (error 122, disk quota exceeded) (error codes gratefully taken from [here](http://mazack.org/unix/errno.php)).

**Edit**: I rather suspected your next question would be "*how do I return this error on a case-by-case basis*", but I thought it sensible to let you ask it anyway.  As you have already been told on several occasions, the best way to do this is with `iptables -j REJECT`, since the resulting error will propagate back to the requesting process in exactly the same way.  Here's an example on the same system with the network up, but a  single `iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -j REJECT` rule prohibiting all `OUTPUT` traffic (NB *this is not a good idea in real life*):

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_add=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"...."..., 64}], msg_controlln=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

With different invocations of `-j REJECT --reject-with ...` different errors are passed back to the requesting process, but all result in an error being passed back.

**Edit 2**: Your mental model of the UNIX networking stack is simply wrong, and the ideas you have formed from it are faulty; specifically iptables **is** the kernel(*).  Part of the problem may be that some programs ignore some errors, some note them but continue, and some terminate.  It is up for any given program to decide what it will do on any given error.  The `ping` program, for example, terminates on `ENETUNREACH`, but on `EPERM` it merely logs an error to `stderr` and continues.  If I understand correctly, this is the behaviour to which you are objecting.

**This is not something you can control unless you are writing the program**.  I understand you would like the kernel to send an error that the software doesn't ignore, but the kernel isn't (as things stand) going to do that for you.  Nothing stops you writing a modified kernel that signals **all** errors with SIGKILL, but Linux doesn't currently do that, and most of us wouldn't want it to.

(*) To be precise, `iptables` is the userspace program that lets us manipulate the netfilter structures inside the kernel.  But the packet  and error handling that results is most definitely a kernel-space phenomenon, not a user-space one.

Comment: Is there a way to make the kernel respond to them all with "no internet for you unless a specific user runs you" ?  ( I do not want to do this with firewall )

Comment: programs seem to have respect for the error message from the kernel. but they do not seem to have much respect for errors originating from the iptables (firewall) this is why I want to block them all from using the internet on the kernel level

Comment: programs seem to "push" it even if iptables DROPs or REJECTs their call (signal).. but if kernel tells them "no internet connectivity" they instantly stop. This is why I want to do this on the kernel level.

Comment: Programs are waiting. and waiting.. and waiting.. until they time out. although iptables is doing a "DROP" or a "REJECT" but if the kernel did a DROP or a REJECT. they instantly shut off.. and give up. this is why I want to do this on the kernel level. not on the iptables level.

Comment: I do not belive there is an example out there for "ping" command within which iptables is able to convince "ping" that network connectivity does not exist and "ping" would give up instantly the same way it does when network connectivity really is not existent.

Comment: I do not belive "REJECT" or "DROP" can simulate the same thing the KERNEL is able to simulate to the program. I do not belive there is a way to make ping return the same error message ( **connect: Network is unreachable** ) based on a rule in the iptables.

Comment: I am okay with the way kernel is able to tell ping to "stop" and ping returns the "( **connect: Network is unreachable** )" instantly. but via iptables.. I did try some **-j REJECT --reject-with ...** it just doesn't make it stop. ping will stall.. other programs will wait for 20-30 seconds until they "time out".

Comment: Yes, you are right (and that is what I said also).  The problem is **that is ping's fault** - its programmer has decided to make it respond to one error by terminating, but another error by logging and continuing.  Your mistake has been to assume that one of those errors is therefore coming from a higher or more "*authoritative*"  place than the other, which it isn't.

Comment: so How can I send it that specific error so that it can terminate ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't.  If that causes you a problem, you will need to find a different way around it.

Comment: `... and beat you with experience` eh :)

Comment: Well at least I have learned sufficient stuff to ask my next questions around these new findings. I have to ask people how to mimic the signal from kernel to the ping.. okay I see this as a progress.

Comment: @NexttoZero without suggesting you should do anything of the sort, *please don't ask it like that*.  My response to Sven above gives an alternative formulation that *might* be less-likely to get closed.

Comment: I would vote to send a question with your alternative wording to U&L.

Comment: @istheEnglishway I knew I could rely on you <grin>!